# How can I hide the rendering of views in the logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to hide the name of what's being rendered, while in development mode. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You are to unsubscribe your `Logger` instance from `ActiveSupport::Notifications`:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.unsubscribe(log)
```

Hope it helps.